# ansible winrm issue ("msg": "the connection plugin 'winrm ## The kind of connection which ansible will make with remote windows node' was not found")

Tags: ansible, winrm

I am getting the below error message while connecting to windows server from linux.
I have installed the pywinrm module. But still getting the error message. Does anyone know about this issue ? TIA

Telnet is working on 5985 and 5986

fatal: [10.10.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the connection plugin 'winrm ## The kind of connection which ansible will make with remote windows node' was not found"}

ansible 2.9.23
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.18 (default, May 25 2022, 14:30:51) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have comment on the same line as connection type identifier in wherever you define connection type for host (likely host vars section of your inventory file). This is not valid and Ansible blindly uses the whole line including the comment: `winrm ## The kind of connection which ansible will make with remote windows node` as a connection type  plugin name - which does not exists. What you want is plugin name `winrm`.

To fix it change this:

```
ansible_connection=winrm ## The kind of connection…
```

to this:

```
ansible_connection=winrm
```

Above will be similar if your host variables are defined in YAML file.

You can keep the comment but it needs to be on its own line  starting with `#`.

Comment: @ssethi Glad to hear it worked. Please mark the question as answered.